# setTimeout issue appearing only in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, settimeout

I have a curious problem that occurs *only* in Safari (I'm using 5.1.4). I have the following code to submit a login form:

```
    $('#login-submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        xDomainUtils.setIframeProxy('showLoginLoader');
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $('#login-form').submit();
        }, 1000);
    });
```

The login never occurs in Safari. The loading gif just spins and spins. I've used the Safari developer tool to step through the code, and it seems to fail after the `}, 1000);` line. It doesn't throw any JavaScript errors - it's almost as if the JavaScript just stops running after that point.

I know it's hard to offer feedback when you can't see the entire codebase - I just wondered if this was a known issue with Safari. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: No it's not a known issue and probably a problem with other code you have. PMI but what is xDomainUtils? If you comment that out what happens? And can you post your form HTML and any other JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that your call to `xDomainUtils` is undefined in Safari. Here's a tip: go to Safari preferences > Advanced and tick 'Show Develop menu in menu bar'. Then go to Develop > Show Web Inspector (or type command-option-i). Under the Console tab (or by hitting escape) you can see all the errors and warnings your javascript generated.